# How to hide the content on checkbox click in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
new Vue({
      el: '#selector',
      data: {
        checked: false,
        unchecked: true
      },
      methods: {
        hidecont() {
          this.checked = !this.unchecked;
        }
      });
```

```html
<div id="selector">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" @click="hidecont" >Options</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="unchecked">
    <p>Text is visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have toggled  using method like check=!checkedd but still i am unable to hide the content.

Initially checkbox and text content should be visible. So once user clicked on checkbox, the content will be in hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` property must be function:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hidecont() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="selector">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" @click="hidecont" >Options</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="!checked">
    <p>Text is visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey mate, check now, just set initial value of checked to true

Comment: i think i got it now mate, check my answer pls :)

Answer (score 1):

Several variables are not required to handle this logic.
You can just save the 'checked' variable, and it's bidirectional binding,
when checkbox is checked, it will be true.
Here is my code.

```
new Vue({
      el: '#selector',
      data: {
        checked: false,
      },
    })
```

```
<div id="selector">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked">Options</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="checked">
    <p>Text is visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can set the initial value of IsChecked to true.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="selector">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="checked" @click="hidecont" >Options</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container" id="app-container" v-if="!checked">
    <p>Text is visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just replaced   `v-if="!checked"` in content div